# Firebase Functions not printing UTF8 Special Characters ��

Tags: node.js, firebase, utf-8, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I use Firebase Functions as a webhook to return JSON responses to DialogFlow (to run a voice bot).

When I return a JSON with sentences containing accented/special characters (é, è, € ...), it prints �� in DialogFlow.

My code :

```js
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const { DialogflowApp } = require('actions-on-google');

exports.cryptoBot = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const app = new DialogflowApp({request, response});

  function launchQuizz (app) {
      textResponse = "Voici la première question :"
      app.ask("<speak>" + textResponse + "</speak>");
  }

  let actionMap = new Map();
  actionMap.set("quizz", launchQuizz);
  app.handleRequest(actionMap);
});
```

It might be very simple to solve, but I've tried different things (utf8 headers, utf8 encode my text...) and looked everywhere and I can't find any solution. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution : Seems like Microsoft Visual Studio saves JS with a weird encoding.

I needed to do File > Save as... > Deploy the little dropdown next the button Save > Select Save with encoding > UTF8